# Plot data in a tabular environment using plgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I have a tabular environment which has two columns representing x and y data. Is there a way for pgfplots to reference the data in that tabular and plot it?

Example table:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 1 & 3.4 \\
 2 & 6.7 \\
 3 & 8.9 \\
 4 & 12.4 \\
 5 & 7.8
 \end{tabular}
```

Current method of using pgfplot:

```
\addplot coordinates {
( 1, 3.4 )
( 2, 6.7 )
( 3, 8.9 )
( 4, 12.4 )
( 5, 7.8 )
};
```

Is there a way for pgfplot to reference the data in the tabular environment instead of repeating the data in the addplot (without using externals files if possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go the other way as you can read your data and either use it in tabular code or in plotting

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=ampersand,row sep=\\,header=false]{
 1 & 3.4 \\
 2 & 6.7 \\
 3 & 8.9 \\
 4 & 12.4 \\
 5 & 7.8 \\
}\mytable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[column type=l,every head row/.style={output empty row}]{\mytable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table{\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]